# How to unenroll user from a course with php

Tags: php, moodle

Using `Moodle 1.9`, I have successfully been able to enroll a user via php with

```
$user   = get_record("user", "id", $mqval['id']);
$course = get_record("course", "id", $cid);

if ( ! enrol_into_course($course, $user, 'manuel')) { 

} else {
  //echo 'success';
}
```

Now I want to unenroll the user the same way. I tried using `unenrol_user`, which didn't work. I also tried `role_unassign` but with no success.

Comment: please post the code that did not work, some sample value`s of all used parameters during enrol_into_course() and unenrol_user(),  and of course the return values from enrol_into_course() and unenrol_user() (true, false or some error?)

Comment: I don't have any code that doesn't work, can't even find a example of how to unenroll :-). Just saw some methods in moodle. But for some reason im not getting any errors on the code from Tivie below but the above code does work.

Answer (score 1):

```
//get instance that can unenrol
$enrols = enrol_get_plugins(true);
$enrolinstances = enrol_get_instances($courseid, true);
$unenrolled = false;
foreach ($enrolinstances as $instance) {
    if (!$unenrolled and $enrols[$instance->enrol]->allow_unenrol($instance)) {
        $unenrolinstance = $instance;
        $unenrolled = true;
    }
}

//unenrol the user in every course he's in
$enrolledusercourses = enrol_get_users_courses($userid);
foreach ($enrolledcourses as $course) {
    //unenrol the user
    $enrols[$unenrolinstance->enrol]->unenrol_user($unenrolinstance, $userid, $roleid);
}
```

Comment: Do i need to include any libs to make this work?  i have require_once('../config.php');
    require_once($CFG->libdir.'/adminlib.php');
    require_once($CFG->libdir.'/filelib.php');
    require_once($CFG->libdir.'/olson.php');

Comment: You should use the moodle autoloader, a subset of Zend autoloader.

Comment: I tried your code but im not getting any errors and its not working. Im placing the code in a new page i created in moodle. The enrol_into_course works. Im not familar with moodle autoloader do i just download that and require it in the page. Moodle newbie

Comment: That works too. For this to work you need  "/user/lib.php", "/user/profile/lib.php" and "/lib/enrollib.php"

Comment: still no go, ill keep trying, i included those files but not the page won't even display anything. so frustrating.

Comment: well, it+s normal that the page isn't showing anything since this script does not output anything...

Comment: You have to test the userid for that course and check if the user is enrolled in the course before and after the script

Comment: Is there a reason why using $unenrolled flag when you could simply break out of foreach once you find correct instance?

Comment: @SubjectX I don't really remember... it was 6 years ago. :/

Answer (score 0):

I have modified above code and its working.

```
//unenrol the user in every course he's in
 $enrols = enrol_get_plugins(true);

$enrolledusercourses = enrol_get_users_courses($user->id);

foreach ($enrolledusercourses as $course) {
    //unenrol the user
    $courseid = $course->id;

    $enrolinstances = enrol_get_instances($courseid, true);
    $unenrolled = false;

    foreach ($enrolinstances as $instance) {
        if (!$unenrolled and $enrols[$instance->enrol]->allow_unenrol($instance)) {
            $unenrolinstance = $instance;
            $unenrolled = true;
        }
    }

    $enrols[$unenrolinstance->enrol]->unenrol_user($unenrolinstance, $user->id, $user->rollid);
}
```

Comment: You need to point out where was the mistake and the steps you taken to fix it clearly so that other people can get help !

Comment: There was only one mistake :

Comment: There was only one mistake in @Tivie answer :

He wrote code for get instance for course before fetch all enrolled course of user.

To fix this issue,first  I have fetch all enrolled user's courses and after that i have write code for get instance of every enrolled course and after that i have unenroll  user from every courses.